# Can I ask "X vs Y" questions here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Consider the following [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610199/the-art-of-programming-java-vs-c-sharp). It has lots of votes, lots of views and lots of useful thorough answers. However, it is closed as not constructive. But it is clearly a good source of information, and very useful judging from the 100,000+ views. Would a similar question comparing and contrasting two similar languages be appropriate for this site? For example, here is a simple mockup of what my question look like:

> I would like to learn (language X) or (language Y) to do (Z). What should I consider while deciding which language to learn? What are some of the pros and cons of each? What are the biggest differences between the two languages?

Comment: ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Comment: It's sad because I know that there is no other site that will get such a high quality answer but I can't ask that kind of question here.

Comment: ["That city is too strict and authoritarian about littering. If it weren't for the fact that its streets were so clean I would never go back."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211439/struggling-to-understand-stack-overflows-philosophy#comment679595_211439)

Comment: @gnat I get that, and I totally agree, which is why I asked here first, and I'm not going to post my question. However, I would say that the question I linked to is a very high quality source of information. If you went to any other forum and asked the exact same Java vs C# question, there would not be nearly as many good and thorough answers even though it would not be considered "off-topic" for the forum.

Comment: Chat is made for this kind of discussion. We have a pretty vibrant chat room here on Programmers, and SO has a number of chat rooms, too.

Comment: you just don't see that "very high quality source" fully. Users with 10K reputation at SO can tell you that there are four deleted answers over there. If it wasn't closed long time ago, there easily could be 40, 400 etc delete-worthy answers. Garbage can pollute this "quality source" infinitely. That's what they mean when they say Q&A format is very poor at handling stuff like that, "Sadly, it didn't work out..." For more detailed analysis, see eg [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6743/31260)